# Get Last non-null cell in a row mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in following structure:

```
id       performance_id     employee_comments   manager_comments
1        23                 NULL                Well done.
2        46                 NULL                Improve Speed
3        46                 Trying to improve   NULL
4        46                 NULL                Put more effort
```

In above structure, at a time, only one comments exist, either employee_comments or manager_comments, not both simultaneously.

I want to fetch last non-empty employee comments and manager_comments in a single row.

I need mysql query to display output as:

```
performance_id     employee_comments   manager_comments
23                 NULL                Well done.
46                 Trying to improve   Put more effort
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the largest `id` for each of the employee comments and manager comments, per performance_id this way:

```
SELECT performance_id, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN employee_comments IS NOT NULL THEN id END) AS emp_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN manager_comments IS NOT NULL THEN id END) AS mgr_id
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY performance_id
```

The above only returns one row per performance_id, with two id numbers. These are the "last" entries, as determined by greater id numbers.

Output:

```
+----------------+--------+--------+
| performance_id | emp_id | mgr_id |
+----------------+--------+--------+
|             23 |   NULL |      1 |
|             46 |      3 |      4 |
+----------------+--------+--------+
```

With that result, you can join it back to the table to retrieve other columns:

```
SELECT t.performance_id, 
    t.employee_comments,
    t.manager_comments
FROM (
    SELECT performance_id, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN employee_comments IS NOT NULL THEN id END) AS emp_id,
      MAX(CASE WHEN manager_comments IS NOT NULL THEN id END) AS mgr_id
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY performance_id
) AS x
JOIN MyTable AS t ON t.id IN (emp_id, mgr_id)
```

Output:

```
+----------------+-------------------+------------------+
| performance_id | employee_comments | manager_comments |
+----------------+-------------------+------------------+
|             23 | NULL              | Well done.       |
|             46 | Trying to improve | NULL             |
|             46 | NULL              | Put more effort  |
+----------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

The above return up to two rows per performance_id. You can use another GROUP BY to force them onto one row:

```
SELECT t.performance_id, 
    MAX(t.employee_comments) AS employee_comments,
    MAX(t.manager_comments) AS manager_comments
FROM (
    SELECT performance_id, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN employee_comments IS NOT NULL THEN id END) AS emp_id,
      MAX(CASE WHEN manager_comments IS NOT NULL THEN id END) AS mgr_id
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY performance_id
) AS x
JOIN MyTable AS t ON t.id IN (emp_id, mgr_id)
GROUP BY performance_id
```

Output:

```
+----------------+-------------------+------------------+
| performance_id | employee_comments | manager_comments |
+----------------+-------------------+------------------+
|             23 | NULL              | Well done.       |
|             46 | Trying to improve | Put more effort  |
+----------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: I haven't tested the above queries, so maybe they need some fixes.

Comment: First query is working, second query is creating problem because error is displaying as "Unknown column 'employee_comments' in 'field list'". It is causing such error because inside FROM clause we have fetched emp_id and mgr_id.

Comment: Okay I had time to test the queries using MySQL 8.0.1. I changed to qualify the columns like `t.performance_id`. They do work, and I include the output given your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by a nested query in MySQL. We will have to do a union and group by `performance_id`

```
 SELECT performance_id ,MAX(employee_comments) 
employee_comments,MAX(manager_comments) manager_comments 
FROM(
SELECT performance_id,employee_comments,manager_comments FROM MyTable 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE manager_comments IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC)AS t)
    UNION
    SELECT performance_id,employee_comments,manager_comments FROM MyTable 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE employee_comments IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC) AS p)) g  GROUP BY performance_id;
```

The above query should work for fetching the last non-empty employee comments and manager_comments 
I have tried and tested it...

Comment: It shows 2 rows for performance_id = 46. Both two rows should be converted to single row.

Comment: @Ishpreet first lets agree on one thing, the last non-null `employee_comments` has `performance_id` =46 and `id`=3 and the last `manager_comments` has `performance_id`=46 and `id`=4 right?
So you want the query to return only one row for matched `performance_id`s?

Comment: @Ishpreet i have redone the query, now test it out.. should have ommited the multiple rows for the same `performance_id`s

Comment: It is converted to single row, but this query is displaying only one row for performance id 46, it is not showing record for performance id = 23

Comment: @Ishpreet but the record with `performance_id`=23 is not the last `employee_comments` or the last `manager_comments` as per your requirement so that's why it will not be on the results...
Unless you have changed your requirements. I have Read again your question just now, correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Technically, Last means first is worked as last if performance_id has single record and latest one is last when performace id has multiple records. Please see structure of output table to clearly understand what output is exactly required.

Comment: @Ishpreet, its now done as per your request. The problem was that i was adding a `LIMIT 1` clause which was getting only one record, but now you should be able to get your result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149708/discussion-between-indago-and-ishpreet).

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT t.id,t.performance_id,t2.employee_comments,t3.manager_comments FROM test1  t join test1 t2 on t2.employee_comments IS NOT NULL and t.manager_comments IS NULL
join test1 t3 on t3.manager_comments IS NOT NULL and t.id < t3.id 
group by t.performance_id
```

Comment: Not displaying correct data. It displays same record for both performance id 23 and 46.

Comment: its gate but last record not get